# problems once uploaded to server

Tags: html, css, file, hyperlink

This all works fine in MAMP but i've uploaded and now the problems start.

heres an image of the code for the link and a grab of the result

[First image](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/236383/link-to-file.tiff)

[Second image](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/236383/result-of-link.tiff)

any ideas?

Comment: When including images, please use JPG, PNG of GIF formats. Tiff files are not really web friendly, and can't be shown inline.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be POSTing to a static HTML file. Try changing the file extension to php, asp, jsp etc. depending on what you're using on the server-side.

Also, for textual content like this, you could simply copy-paste the text intead of capturing screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it was in the .js file, it was pointing to POST and should have been GET